# Kendo jQuery Grid , Get text on dropdown filter

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can i get the text field of a dropdown in the column filter?

I have the following example : https://dojo.telerik.com/izUviSID/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the filters like so:

```
    function checkFilters() {
       let myGrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
       let filter = myGrid.dataSource.filter();
       if (filter) {
          console.log(filter.logic);
          console.log(myGrid.dataSource.filter);
       }
    }
```

I added this to your dojo too: https://dojo.telerik.com/izUviSID/3

You can also check individual filters if they exist like so:

```
filter.filters[0]
```

The way you have your filters set up though, there is no text value for the filters. Find out more info in the Kendo demos/docs https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

Comment: Is there a way to show "Ford" instead of 1 when i click when column filter?

Comment: One way would be to set up your brands as an enum - more info here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/filterable.operators.enums#filterable.operators.enums

Comment: But that means that i have to stop using the checkbox filter .

Comment: There was no detail as to your exact requirements in your question! :)  Anyway - have a look at the Kendo demos - they should show you the way: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-multi-checkboxes